# Tasks.json does not accept wildcard for multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, vscode-tasks

I have a folder with multiple cpp files that I want to compile to a DLL with g++ (MinGW).

My Tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Compiler",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "D:\\Programme\\MinGW\\bin\\g++",
        "args": [
            "-c",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
            "-I${workspaceFolder}\\..\\..\\sdk\\include"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Linker",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "D:\\Programme\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}\\**.o",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\Plugin.dll",
            "-L${workspaceFolder}\\..\\..\\sdk\\lib",
            "-lExampleLib",
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Build Plugin",
        "dependsOn": [
            "Compiler",
            "Linker"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

When I execute one of the tasks, it just tries to compile one file named `*.cpp` or tries to link one file named `*.o`, which is wrong of course.

```
> Executing task: D:\Programme\MinGW\bin\g++ -c 'D:\...\Plugins\PluginDev\*.cpp' '-ID:\...\Plugins\PluginDev\..\..\sdk\include' <

 g++.exe: error: D:\...\Plugins\PluginDev\*.cpp: Invalid argument
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a build tool like Make, CMake, MSBuild

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that replacing `${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp` with `*.cpp` works after adding options and changing cwd:

```
"args": [...],
"options": {
   "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
}
```